# Using regex to select word before another word which starts with a capital letter

Tags: regex

I would like to select all adjectives in a German sentence.

As all German nouns are capitalized, I though one way would be to look for capitalized words and select the previous word. If the selected word wasn't a definite or indefinite article it should be an adjective.

Could someone help me with a regular expression to do this?

Comment: This logic won't work, i.e. "Ich baue Häuser". "baue" isn't an adjective ...

Comment: Good point VMai. But if I find a way of selecting the word before a noun I will be able to filter out verbs,articles etc. shub, I am not experienced using regex and would appreciate some help, its up to you whether to help or not

Comment: Usually you would search for a word boundary, followed by one or more lower case characters of given set (a-zäöüß should do for a first approach), followed by a blank, followed by a capital character of a similar set, followed by some lower case characters. But it won't match "Große Häuser" ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
\b\u[[:alpha:]]*\b
```

You will need to switch on case sensitive regex searching (so that \u only matches upper case chars). If your regex engine supports character collation you may need to switch it on.